# tooltipster.js: title is removed when tooltipstered

Tags: tooltipster

Here's another clue:

https://jsfiddle.net/68umt5b3/

Please note, that title of `<span>` is getting lost after first hovering. How can I preserve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to accomplish that, as otherwise the browser would display a native tooltip on top of Tooltipster's tooltip. Whatever you want to accomplish, do it in another way, for example with some "data-title" attribute.